# According to JSONAPI standards, does the server respond with the JWT Token in the response body or response header?

Tags: httpresponse, jwt, json-api

No where in the [JSONAPI doc](http://jsonapi.org/format/) explains anything about tokens. I understand they're two different subjects but I had no luck finding a direct answer on the site nor on the web.

Assuming the request is authenticated, are the JSONAPI standards to return the JWT token in the response body or response header?

I was thinking it would go best in the `meta` or `attributes` object. How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it the id of a sessions object
Put it in meta
Or header

All are fine.  I prefer treating it like a session resource.